# Find groups having all values in given column match specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

With table `t` being

```
|id| sport      |
|1 | football   |
|1 | football   |
|1 | baseball   |
|2 | football   |
|2 | football   |
|3 | football   |
|4 | football   |
|4 | golf       |
|4 | golf       |
|4 | baseball   |
|4 | football   |
|5 | football   |
|5 | football   |
|6 | basketball |
|6 | football   |
|6 | football   |
```

Grouping by `id`, how can I select only ids where all values of sport = football?  Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM t 
GROUP BY id
HAVING ALL SPORT = 'football'
```

In order to return

```
|id| sport      |
|2 | football   |
|2 | football   |
|3 | football   |
|5 | football   |
|5 | football   |
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the trivial solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM t
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN sport = 'football' THEN 1 END) = COUNT(*)
)
```

Comment: what tweak would I need to make in order to change... ALL values of sport = football into ANY values of sport = football?

Comment: I guess `... IN (SELECT id FROM t WHERE sport = 'football')`

Answer (score 2):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM t 
             GROUP BY id
             HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sport != 'football' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0);
```

## EDIT:

> *what tweak would I need to make in order to change... ALL values of sport = football into ANY values of sport = football?*

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM t
             WHERE sport = 'football');
```

Comment: what tweak would I need to make in order to change... ALL values of sport = football into ANY values of sport = football?

Comment: @JohnF Simple IN/EXISTS will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In a column where all the values are the same, the minimum and maximum values are equal. You could utilize this property in a `having` clause:

```
SELECT   id, MAX(sport)
FROM     t
GROUP BY id
HAVING   MIN(sport) = 'football' AND MAX(sport) = 'football'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the original rows, use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.sport = 'footbal' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.sport <> t.sport
                 );
```

Otherwise, use

```
having min(sport) = max(sport) and max(sport) = 'football'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned into above question, as a solution to it please try executing following SQL select query

```
    select * from(SELECT id, sport FROM `t`
        group by id, sport) as q group by q.id having count(q.id) = 1 
and sport = 'football'
```